# Jsoup Extracting Info using .select

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract my liked songs from Pandora using Jsoups .select.

HTML:

```
<div class="user_feed clearfix">
    <div id="profile_tip_spacer">&nbsp;</div>


        <!-- FEED ITEM START 6008047449161974 -->
        <div class="section clearfix"
             webname="genericprofile"
             listenerId="1326689853"
             feedId="6008047449161974"
             feedIndex="1"
                                        >
            <div class="infobox">
                <div class="infobox-thumb">
                    <div class="owner_profile_image">

                            <a href="/profile/genericprofile">
                                <div class="feed_profile pfora-img-square pfora-img-square--50x50" style="background-image:url(/img/no_listener_image.png)"></div>
                            </a>

                                                                                                                </div><!--  owner_profile_image -->
                </div><!-- infobox-thumb -->
                <div class="infobox-body">
                    <div class="like_song feed_details clearfix">
                                                    <h3 class="hed-4">
                            <div class="newsfeed_text clearfix"><span class="user_name"><span class="user_name self"><a href="/profile/genericprofile" fbid="0" webname="genericprofile" class="facebookName">genericprofile</a></span> likes</span> <span class="newsfeed_song_name"><a href="/logic/man-of-year-single/man-of-year">Man Of The Year</a></span> <span>by</span> <span class="newsfeed_song_name"><a href="/logic">Logic</a></span><br />
                                <ul class="list-h-1">
```

Using this Java Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(
                "http://www.pandora.com/profile/genericprofile")
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements links = doc.select("div.user_feed.clearfix");
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println(title);
    for (Element e : links) {
        System.out.println(links);
    }

}
```

}

I have been able to display the user_feed clearfix class but have been unable to .select all of the section clearfix elements using a

```
doc.select("div.user_feed.clearfix > div.section clearfix");
```

Ultimately my end goal is to be able to get the href link that contains the song name and artist, in this case Man of the Year by Logic, and manipulate it using the String class.

Comment: You used a whitespace where you need to use a `.` for the second `clearfix` class selector.

Comment: Even using the "." instead of the white space I unfortunately do not get anything back in my links variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
div.section.clearfix
```

to select `div` with classes of `section` and `clearfix`.

Comment: Whenever I use div.section.clearfix I do not get anything back when I attempt to output it.